# How to add project

Tags: java, eclipse

i am using eclipse.
In eclipse for a class how can i invoke the "build path" property(which appears on right click) ?

Then i want to invoke the "configure build path" property and add a project in the project tab.

I know that i can do it by right click etc but I want to write code for that.Is it possible?Help

Comment: make them separate questions, each on a line so we can help you better

Comment: here you go . I think its better now.

Answer (score 0):

> add a project in the project tab?

Here is how to add a new project, from `Package Explorer`, right click and choose `New->Java Project`, in the wizard, define your project name, then Next until Finish.

From the new created project, right click and choose `New->Class`, although i would recommend you make a `New->Package` first